# C++/OpenCV - VideoCapture fails for string received from iterator

Tags: c++, opencv

**Snippet:**

```
string tmpString=*myIt;                  //-------- myIt is iterator

string tmpString1="videos/origVid/graz-gleisdorf_1.avi";

cout << typeid(*myIt).name() << "\t" << typeid(tmpString).name() << "\t" << typeid(tmpString1).name() << endl;

cout << *myIt << endl << tmpString << endl << tmpString1 << endl;

VideoCapture cap=VideoCapture(tmpString1);
```

**Output:**

```
Ss  Ss  Ss 

videos/origVid/graz-gleisdorf_1.avi

videos/origVid/graz-gleisdorf_1.avi

videos/origVid/graz-gleisdorf_1.avi
```

**Question:**
`tmpString`, `*myItr`, `tmpString1` all are of same type yet `VideoCapture` works only for `tmpString1`! Can someone throw some pointers?

I wish to read .avi files from folder; so I iterate through all the files and try reading them through `VideoCpature`. But I fail to do so using the iterator. `cap` fails for both `tmpString` and `*myItr`.

C++: `VideoCapture::VideoCapture(const String& filename)`

Comment: Please elaborate your question little more pls

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You forgot to add a question. You forgot to format your code as code. You forgot to explain what you want to do. You forgot to explain what you have tried.

Comment: Random guess: you have a line break or other space characters at the end of `tmpString`.

Comment: Random guess 2:  this isn't related to Opencv, is it ? Is it's just a string handling problem, please remove the opencv tag.

Comment: I've kept opencv just for VideoCapture . I doubt if "const String& filename" has some role to play in error.

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed problem with string handling. Character at end was creating trouble. Regret the inconvenience caused due to my naiveness and stupidity.

tmpString.erase(std::remove(tmpString.begin(),tmpString.end(),char(13)),tmpString.end());